# Which module allows for tracking recently viewed content per user?

Tags: users

I am searching for a module that will enable me to track recently viewed content per user. I found the [Recently read](https://drupal.org/project/recently_read) module but it does not appear to enable me to configure it per content type. For example, I want to show all recently viewed content by this given user for content type a and content type b. Is anyone aware of a module that would allow this?

Comment: Have a look at some of my answers at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A39516+visitors+module ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Recently Read](https://drupal.org/project/recently_read) module does not allow you out of the box to be configure per content type, but it seems to me that the views you create to show the content can easily be filtered by content type. See comments [#3](https://drupal.org/comment/6977062#comment-6977062) and [#5](https://drupal.org/comment/6977658#comment-6977658) of [this thread](https://drupal.org/node/1887126).

Also a quick scan of the modules source code tells me, that there is still support for relationships in views. So you should be able to follow the configuration guidelines in the linked comments to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The only issue I see with that is you configure x number of recently read nodes, my guess this is not per node type so it may miss the content I want to track.  I'll look into it deeper. Thanks again.